# Get text between specific strings as different strings in regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have been trying to get text between two strings-('Item' and 'Item') but since 'Item' is present multiple times throughout the large document(which is itself a string) i get almost all whole of the document.
I can't figure out the regex code to get text between one 'item' and the next 'Item' till the last 'Item' as different strings.

I have tried regex codes but i can't figure it out.

First try :

```
(?<=Item)(.*)(?=Item)
```

Second try:

```
value = search('Item(.+)Item', text)
if value is not None:
    value = value.group(1)
```

The First try selects almost all of document

The Second try only gives the first occurrence of text between 'Item' and 'Item'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try making it non greedy. Since you capture the value in a group, you can omit the lookarounds. `Item(.*?)Item`

Comment: Could you give sample text and expected result?

Comment: Sample Text: 'Item Hello this is a sample Item String on StackOverflow Item Posted on a Item Wednesday' . Result: Hello this a sample ,   String on Overflow,  Posted on a , Wednesday

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried doing that but it sill returns only the first occurrence

Comment: I thinks @The fourth bird answer works: https://regex101.com/r/UkcokL/4/

Comment: @DeepDhillon I think that is because you use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). Try using re.findall instead

Comment: If you want to match between every occurrence of `Item` you could use the lookarounds. If you must match it in pairs you could omit the lookarounds.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for your help too! I now understand the logic behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

string = 'Item Hello this is a sample Item String on StackOverflow Item Posted on a Item Wednesday'

print re.findall(r"(?<=Item ).+?(?= Item|$)",  string)
```

**Output:**

```
['Hello this is a sample', 'String on StackOverflow', 'Posted on a', 'Wednesday']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=Item )      # positive lookbehind, make sure we have "Item " before
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?= Item|$)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have "Item " or end of line after
```

Comment: This worked ! Thank you @Toto . I am new to regex but i definitely  have learnt a new useful method!